# Why is look-up not working properly in Chrome PDF viewer

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, pdf, look-up

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports) running Big Sur 11.6. Chrome is Version 94.0.4606.71 (Official Build) (x86_64).
When I'm using look-up in Chrome PDF viewer, it would automatically open up the dictionary but no pop-up window next to the word I chose.

Comment: Chrome tends to ignore the Apple standard toolbox [imo, as far as it can, it just tries really hard to be as cussed as possible ;)